# What does quotations around a single word in this sentence signify?

Tags: meaning

What does quotations around a single word signify? For example in a letter or email- Thank you for sharing the information. I'm reading it and "listening" (as always).

Does it signify emphasis? As in the person would you like to emphasize to you they are listening to the information provided.

Comment: POB, whatever.  It may be sarcasm.  It may not.

Comment: The author's meaning is tied up in the author's context, which we don't really know. You are the best judge, and if you are not sure, just ask them.

Comment: These are known in the trade as ["scare quotes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes). Their purpose is to flag a word, expression, description, or slogan as being not entirely appropriate or accurate, in the opinion of the author. They are often used ironically or satirically.

Comment: @John Lawler Only if they are used with punctuation knowledge and with ironic or satirical intent.

Comment: It's always a little hard to tell whether a punctuation mark has been deployed with punctuation knowledge and ironic or satirical intent. Commas tell no tales.

Answer (score 1):

Either the person knows how to use quotation marks and is being sarcastic; or doesn't, and is grateful. It sounds to me, from this tiny snippet, that s/he is ignorant and appreciative.

Comment: Do you mean ignorant as in not knowing how to  use quotations marks the proper way and being appreciative for the info provided?

Comment: Exactly @seabird.

Comment: I have never met this person before.Thanks @wys1wyg. I took it as sarcastic but I know in past correspondence they really want to learn about the particular subject I send information with regards to. Maybe he was emphasizing the word learning as a form of eagerness.

Comment: I hope so, and agree with @Ian MacDonald that there might be a hint of self-consciouness in there too.

Comment: So not necessarily they were being sarcastic? Self conscious as in not being able to fully comprehend all the info.  We all experience that in life.

Comment: The way I read it, I too interpreted it this way. It is becoming more and more frequent to see quotes used on the Internet as a way of emphasising a word (by people who can't think of a better way to do it, presumably). It seems like an odd shoot-off of the traditional way of writing a word in \*asterisks\* to indicate emphasis—though I can't figure out how quotes can possibly be easier to find on a keyboard than an asterisk… (Note that “\*asterisks\*” on here and many other places = “*asterisks*”.)

Answer (score 1):

From the (brief) context that you have provided, it is likely that this person is genuinely appreciative. The reason "learning" is written in quotes is likely because the writer feels they are not actually learning and feel embarrassed.

Comment: I know they want to learn and it's possible they may understand some of the info but not all. They have been appreciative in the past.. @Ian MacDonald thank you.

Answer (score 0):

{Quote ... unquote} =

- for lack of a better word
- emphasis
- correlation to another known concept/situation
- denote tongue-in-cheek sarcasm

e.g.,

- **for lack of a better word**

  We were trekking at the edges of the jungles of Kalimantan. One morning our guide harvested some milky liquid from nearby palms. He yelled us up and gestured "drinking" with his thumb pointing into his mouth, and then pointing to his plastic bag of liquid, saying "Toddy, toddy, ..." We were puzzled and so he said "Vodka, coconut, vodka". We had only brought our cycling water bottles with us from America, so he fashioned some **'cups'** out of palm leaves.

  Thus that morning we sat at the cliff watching the sea, while drinking **'vodka'** out of palm **'cups'**.
- **correlation to another known concept/situation**

  Our employers would persistently admonish us "You have to learn from one another." So much, so that we had to produce evidence for 10 instances of having learned from a colleague, which would count towards 25% of each of our bonus pay. Most of use had racked up only 3 or 4 instances of **'learning'**, when we had only one month left till the annual performance review.

  I knew Henry had a lot of information about the shipping operations. So I wrote him an email asking him a couple of questions. He replied me with some really interesting facts. Then I asked him to clarify a few points, to which he responded with rather succinct answers. I wrote to thank him saying "Thanks Henry, I am **'learning'** from you." He responded with "Me too, :-)" . With that email exchange, I had racked up another five **'learning'** points.
- **Emphasis**

  **"Learning"** is an essential feature of a machine intelligence for it to be useful. In old-school technology, we say the **"teachability"** of an **"artificial intelligence"**. In new-school technology, we lean more towards the **"learnability"** of a "machine intelligence".

  A robustly designed and engineered machine intelligence should vastly and always be opportunistically **"learning"**.
- **Sarcasm**

  Raju is a very driven and **"enthusiastic"** engineer. By **"enthusiastic"**, I should mean **"busy-body"**. So **"enthusiastic"** was he, that he often fed back to us nitty-gritties he had observed in our work.

  One day, as usual, he sent me a couple of notes complaining. Actually **"whining"**. That day, I decided that I too should be just as **"driven"**. Therefore to each of his remarks he sent me, I would reply with "Thx Raju, I am **'learning'** (-;".

Comment: Emphasis is not a kosher use of quotes; it shows that the user doesn't understand how to use quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a standard grammatical construct, but a widespread use of quotes is to mean something like "so called". So someone who believed that all elections were rigged might write about our "elected" government. If this is the case then the writer doesn't believe he is really learning.

However **another widespread (but definitely incorrect) use of quotes is for emphasis**. So someone who has never worked for their exams before might say 'I am going to "really" study for this exam'. The correct way to do this is with *italics* (underscore or CAPS works if italics isn't available), but I've seen enough cases of using quotes for this to say its common usage. However while you should be ready to understand this usage, please don't do it.

Only context can determine which your writer means.